# React - How to re-render a component using another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have a `NavBar` component that has a list of dynamically generated links (these links are generated after querying my backend for some `categories`). These links are stored inside a child component of the NavBar, called `DrawerMenu`.

The `NavBar` is a child of the main `App.js` component.

In my `Category` component, I have a "delete" function that deletes a category. Once I delete a category I want to remove the link to it in the `NavBar`. How would I go about doing this?

For further context, my components are given below:

### DrawerMenu component

```
class DrawerMenu extends Component {
  state = {
    menuItems: [] // Takes a series of objects of the shape { name: "", link: "" }
  }

  getData = (query) => {
    // Query backend for category data and set it to this.state.menuItems
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData(menuItemsQuery)
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, handleDrawerClose, open } = this.props
    const { menuItems } = this.state

    const drawer = (classes, handleDrawerClose) => (
      <div>
          ...

          {
            menuItems.map((menuItem, index) => (
              <Link color="inherit" key={index} to={menuItem.link} className={classes.drawerLink} component={RouterLink}>
                <ListItem button className={classes.drawerListItem} onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                  <ListItemText primary={menuItem.name} />
                </ListItem>
              </Link>
            ))
          }
          
          ...
      </div>
    )
    
    ...

    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          anchor='left'
          open={open}
          onClose={handleDrawerClose}
          classes={{
            paper: `${open ? classes.drawerOpen : null} ${!open ? classes.drawerClose : null}`,
          }}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
          }}
        >
          {drawer(classes, handleDrawerClose)}
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

### NavBar component

```
function PrimarySearchAppBar(props) {
    return (
        <div className={classes.grow}>
            
            ...
            
            <DrawerMenu
                classes={classes}
                handleDrawerClose={handleDrawerClose}
                open={open}
            />
            
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

### Category component

```
class Category extends Component {
    ...
    
    deleteCategory = async () => {
        // Code to request backend to delete category
        this.props.history.push(`/`)
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can use Content API https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: You can add another state for flagging that a server request is made and you can pull the new data after deleting

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways of doing this: You can either use a state management tool, like `Redux` or pass your state down the component tree as props.

Redux is often used when several components depend on the same state or when the component that depends on a state is several layers deep, so it would get cumbersome to pass it down as props.

I'll assume your component tree is not very large, so I will create a simple example passing props down the tree.

```
class DrawerMenu extends Component {
  // We're gonna manage the state here, so the deletion
  // will actually be handled by this component
  state = {
    menuItems: [] // Takes a series of objects of the shape { name: "", link: "" }
  }

  handleDelete = (id) => {
    let updatedMenuItem = [...this.state.menuItems]; //Create a copy
    updatedMenuItem = updatedMenuItem(item => item.id !== id) // Remove the 
deleted item
    this.setState({
       menuItems: updatedMenuItem
    })    
   
  }
  ...

   // Then wherever you render the category component
   <Category handleDelete = {handleDelete}/> //Pass a reference to the delete method

}
```

**Category Component**

```
 class Category extends Component {
    ...
    
    deleteCategory = async () => {
        // Code to request backend to delete category
        this.props.handleDelete(categoryId) //Pass the id of the category
        this.props.history.push(`/`)
    }
    
    ...
}
```

I would suggest reading about state management, it is a core concept in React and you will use it everywhere. Redux and Context API for example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Dennis Vash deleted their answer, they are correct, but perhaps not descriptive enough in the solution.

The way you delete the category is not to call the backend itself from inside the category component, because then the navbar doesn't know that you made a call, but to call a callback that is in an ancestor shared by both the category component and the navbar to delete a category, and then rerequest the categories list from the server. In the example below, this ancestor that is shared is `MyCategoriesProvider`

Because the category component is likely to be in a much different place (or multiple places) in the tree than the NavBar, it's best to use context.

Honestly, this is a great place for redux, but I'm not going to push redux on you and instead will just demo a Context solution.

```
// We're going to create a context that will manage your categories
// The only job of this context is to hold the current categories, 
// and supply the updating functions. For brevity, I'll just give 
// it a handleDelete function.
// Ideally, you'd also store the status of the request in this context
// as well so you could show loaders in the app, etc

import { createContext } from 'react';

// export this, we'll be using it later
export const CategoriesContext = createContext();

// export this, we'll render it high up in the app
// it will only accept children
export const MyCategoriesProvider = ({children}) => {

   // here we can add a status flag in case we wanted to show a spinner
   // somewhere down in your app
   const [isRequestingCategories,setIsRequestingCategories] = useState(false);

   // this is your list of categories that you got from the server
   // we'll start with an empty array
   const [categories,setCategories] = useState([]);

   const fetch = async () => {
      setIsRequestingCategories(true);
      setCategories(await apiCallToFetchCategories());
      setIsRequestingCategories(false);
   }

   const handleDelete = async category => {
       await apiCallToDeleteCategory(category);
       // we deleted a category, so we should re-request the list from the server
       fetch();
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      // when this component mounts, fetch the categories immediately
      fetch();

      // feel free to ignore any warnings if you're using a linter about rules of hooks here - this is 100% a "componentDidMount" hook and doesn't have any dependencies
   },[]);

   return <CategoriesContext.Provider value={{categories,isRequestingCategories,handleDelete}}>{children}</CategoriesContext.Provider>

}

// And you use it like this:

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyCategoriesProvider>
      <SomeOtherComponent>
      <SomeOtherComponent> <- let's say your PrimarySearchBar is in here somewhere
      <SomeOtherComponent>
    </MyCategoriesProvider>
  )

}

// in PrimarySearchBar you'd do this:

function PrimarySearchBar(props) => {
   const {categories} = useContext(CategoriesContext); // you exported this above, remember?
   
   // pass it as a prop to navbar, you could easily put the useContext hook inside of any component
   return <NavBar categories={categories}/>

}


// in your category component you could do this:

class Category extends Component {
     render() {
        // Don't forget, categoriesContext is the thing you exported way up at the top
        <CategoriesContext.Consumer>
           {({handleDelete}) => {
                return <button onClick={() => handleDelete(this.props.category)}>
           }}
        </CategoriesContext.Consumer>
     }
}
```

EDIT:

I see you're mixing class and functional components, which is fine. You should check out [this article](https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/) on how to use the context api in either of them - in functional components you typically use a `useContext` hook, while in class components you'll use a consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I would just refresh the list of categories that come from the server, after the delete request is done.

I'd do it as follows:

- I would make the drawer component not so smart, making it receive the list of menuItems.

```
<DrawerMenu
    classes={classes}
    handleDrawerClose={handleDrawerClose}
    open={open}
    items={/* ... */}
/>
```

This is an important step, because now, to refresh the list of items rendered, you just pass another list. The server-side logic remains disconnected from this component in this way.

- I'm not sure where you render the `Category` components, but supposing it is rendered outside the `PrimarySearchAppBar` it seems that this menuItems might need to be passed to the components from an upper level. I see 2 solutions:

  1. I'd do the request for the menuItems from the same place where I do the request for the categories:

```
const App = props => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([])
    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = React.useState([])

    const fetchCategories = useCallback(()=> {
        yourApi.getCategories().then(categories => setCategories(categories))
    })

    const fetchMenuItems = useCallback(() => {
        yourApi.getMenuItems().then(menuItems => setMenuItems(menuItems))
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCategories()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
       fetchMenuItems()
    }, [categories])

    const handleDeleteCategory = useCallback(idToDelete => {
        yourApi.deleteCategory(idToDelete).then(fetchCategories)
    })

    return (
        <div>
             <PrimarySearchAppBar menuItems={menuItems}/>
             <Categories categories={categories} onDeleteClick={handleDeleteCategory} />
        </div>
    )

}
```

2. you can do the same thing but do it with a provider and using the content API if you do not want to have all the logic here. It is good to have smart/fetches/server-side logic in a top level component and then pass down props to dumb components.

PS.
There is also a nice hook to make fetches easier:
https://github.com/doasync/use-promise

I currently use a custom version of a usePromise hook I found because I added some interesting features. I can share it if you want but I don't want to add noise to the answer.